# Sentence with doubtful syntax

Tags: conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, ellipses, adverb-position

A sentence that does not seem right on account of syntax

- Not only are verbs largely uninflected in English, but also nouns, pronouns and adjectives.

This sentence seems very unusual although it is understandable. I can't  tell what is wrong with it, if anything is. Possibly the adverb "only" is not properly positioned but I can't assert that.

Would someone confirm that there is a problem and explain what is wrong? Otherwise, can someone show that there is no  problem?

Comment: _Not only ... but also_ is a coordinating conjunction; the subject-auxiliary inversion in the first clause is because of the negation. The sentence is fine; the verb phrase _are largely uninflected in English_ is deleted from the end of the second clause by conjunction reduction, leaving only the subject conjoined noun phrase _nouns, pronouns, and adjectives_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would this be correct:  "Not only are verbs largely uninflected in English, but also **are** nouns, pronouns and adjectives."?

Comment: No, that's ungrammatical; the original was correct. You're following an incorrect rule.

Comment: @JohnLawler Wouldn't you say that, if the OP's looking for an alternative, they could use "but _so are_ nouns, pronouns and adjectives" getting rid of the rather clumsy _also_ altogether?

Comment: @LPH your example has negative+positive coordination. "Not only" is not a coordinator, but a modifier in the first coordinate. The second coordinate is a noun phrase introduced by the coordinator "but".

Comment: I'd use 
'Not only are verbs largely uninflected in English, so also are nouns, pronouns and adjectives.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "So also" is found in plenty as correlative with a preceding "as" (as…so also): in the words in CGEL there is an equation of the conjoins. "Not only…so also" is apparently not found; whatever the interpretation of this combination  "but" not being used, as in combination with "not" it makes for (still in the words of CGEL)  a _distinction_ between the conjoins, appears to deprive the idea in the correlative of this distinction, thus leaving that of an equation (not entirely identified in "not only"); it is this distinction that forces us (1/2)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth to look at the first conjoin as given ground ("only" makes surprising the content in the first clause and even more surprising that in the second). It seems that "but" has to be retained: "Not only are verbs largely uninflected in English, but so also are nouns, pronouns and adjectives.". (2/2)

Comment: 'Not only are varietal selection and improvement a continuing need but so also is the maintenance of existing varieties.' [Encyclopedia Britannica; ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/s/but+so+also+are)]

Comment: @JohnLawler Doesn't *conjunction reduction* eliminate only conjunctions?

Comment: @touchstone: No, _conjunction reduction_ is a name, not a description. It applies to conjuncts, and deletes repeated material in them. (In the preceding sentence, conjunction reduction took out the second _it_, the subject  of _deletes_.) [More information here](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction)

Comment: It's certainly pretentious.

Comment: I'd suggest "Not only verbs but also nouns, pronouns, and adjectives are largely uninflected in English."

Answer (score 1):

> Not only are verbs largely uninflected in English, but also nouns, pronouns and adjectives.

There's nothing wrong.

As John Lawler points out, *Not only ... but also* is a conjunction along the lines of "either ... or"

The example equates to

*Verbs are largely uninflected in English **and so are** nouns, pronouns and adjectives.*

Expanded further to demonstrate the two coordinate clauses:

*Verbs are largely uninflected in English **and** nouns, pronouns and adjectives are largely uninflected in English.*

An alternative view might be

Verbs are largely uninflected in English in the manner of nouns, pronouns and adjectives.

But this does not express exactly the same idea as *nouns, pronouns and adjectives* can only be considered as an a priori standard.

Answer (score -1):

I believe my first impression could be justified (problem). After having thought about the several comments to the question, it finally occurred to me that "*not only… but also*" was a unit that could leave some trace somewhere and the  check I made was conclusive.

> ([Grammarly: Parallelism with "not  only…but also](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism-with-not-only-but-also/))
> When using "not only . . . but also" in a sentence, parallelism should be the goal. It means that the words following both parts of this correlative conjunction (i.e., not only and but also) should belong to the same parts of speech. For example, if a verb follows "not only", then a verb should also follow "but also". Using different parts of speech after each part of "not only . . . but also" makes the sentence imbalanced and, frankly, just awkward.

A slight change according to this principle, which results in the  sentence below, would appear to give back to the initial sentence a normal feel, but that is without taking into account another principle, the verb/subject inversion in sentences beginning with "not only" ([cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also)).

- <s>Not only  verbs are largely uninflected in English, but also nouns, pronouns and adjectives.</s>

However, if the verb is changed into the corresponding noun there is no problem in preserving parallelism.

- In English, absence of inflection is characteristic of not only  verbs, but also  of nouns, pronouns and adjectives.

*Another option, perhaps better*

- In english, not only verbs but also nouns, pronouns and adjectives are largely uninflected.

Comment: "Not only .. but also" is not correlative. "Not only" can be repeated in layered coordination, e.g. "Practice among authorities varies [**not only** on the question of the parental means scale, **not only** in the way they assess parental incomes, **but** also in the amounts which they give]". "Not only" thus functions as a modifier, not a marker of correlative coordination. The location of "not only" the simply reflects the range of positions available to focusing adverbs like "only".

Comment: @BillJ I can't follow your argument; for instance it is accepted that "the…the" is correlative, yet you can add conjoins: "the cheaper, the closer, the faster, the better". Is not this construction correlative in your theory?

Comment: The point is that "not only" is not a marker of correlative coordination, but a modifier in the first coordinate. My example proves this.

Comment: Your "satisfying, balanced sentence," *In English, are largely uninflected not only ...* has very un-English word order.

Comment: @PeterShor Is there a readily understandable  principle that could be referred to in order to explain that?

Comment: We generally invert the subject-verb only in questions or **after** negative adverbial phrases. (There are some other times we are also allowed to do it — [see this webpage](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html).) You're trying to use inversion **before** the negative phrase *not only*, and it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence structure is a bit awkward even if I ignore the grammatical error. Still, the main issue that I see is that you have *but also* preceding a dependent clause rather than an independent clause.

Perhaps something such as the following could work:

> **Verbs are not the only words that are largely uninflected in English. Additionally, nouns, pronouns, and adjectives are largely uninflected as well.**

If you wanted a compound sentence then:

> **In addition to verbs, the English language has largely uninflected nouns, pronouns, and adjectives.**

The underlying issue (the awkwardness that I spoke of) is that you are really going to have to be unnecessarily wordy to make this work. The best solution to limit wordiness would be this:

> **English is largely uninflected.**

(I took the last one directly from the Oxford Languages Dictionary.)

*Thanks to @Hellion for catching word usage mistakes.*

*Thanks to @LPH for catching that the compound sentence example is very weak. I have created a new example in its place.*

Comment: You can't have subordination with correlative conjunctions, I don't think so.

Comment: @Hellion Thanks, thought it was wrong. Corrected.

Comment: @LPH Thanks for that. I have created a new example in its place.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is that "but also" would not be preceding a dependent clause, this being so as with correlative conjunctions, which are neither plain coordinating conjunctions nor subordinating conjunctions, there is preservation of an equality between the correlated parts, as there is for instance in the case of coordination of independent clauses. "Not only …but" is not a subordinating correlative but instead a coordinating correlative and so, in this sentence there is no subordination.

Comment: @Joseph What grammatical error? The second coordinate contains 'gapping', where the verb phrase "are largely uninflected in English is omitted but recoverable from the first coordinate.

Comment: @LPH You're wrong about that for the reason I gave you in my first comment about your answer.

Comment: @BillJ I don't know what to say to you: CGEL(13.33)  does assert that _not only …but_ is a correlative coordinator (not a subordinator) and that is what I go by but the fine analysis of why it is a coordinator is not a theory that figures in my background. I couldn't set out to demonstrate that with my present grammatical background. I have to take on faith that this is a coordinating correlative.

Comment: @LPH If you're referring to Quirk et al's CGEL, it has been proved to be wrong on many things and this is one of them. I gave you a very precise reason in my comment 14 Oct to your answer. Please read it again

Comment: @BillJ That is the reference, yes. You say that "not only" modifies the verb; I don't agree: this locution does not bear upon the verb so as to say that verbs should have an additional characteristic on top of being largely uninflected, but it bears upon the whole clause. Next, you call "not only" a coordinator; that is not what is reckoned by CGEL and not what I find logical either: there is really a coordinator but it is the _correlative_ coordinator "_not only…**but**_".  What is clear to me, if nothing else is, is that "not only" bears upon the whole clause; (1/2)

Comment: @BillJ as such it prepares the reader for another idea, to be found in the next clause (or the second sentence of a cleft sentence structure) and it contributes therefore to a connection. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH I never said that "not only" was a coordinator!

Comment: @BillJ Of course not, I know that, you say it is not one, but denying that it is one understates that others call it that, which is not exact: by itself it is not a coordinator.

Comment: @LPH. In that case why did you say three comments ago, quote: "Next you call "not only" a coordinator ...".

Comment: @BillJ Oh! Sorry! That is an error. It should be "Next you say that "not only" is not a coordinator.